# Is there a ternary operator in handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

In Handlebars, is there a ternary operator? I don't mean `if else`; I mean like `a == true ? "a" : "b"`.

Comment: Have you checked the official web-site: http://handlebarsjs.com/? It contains tutorials...

Comment: I have checked the official web-site.But I didn't see the explaintions of the ternary oprerator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can build your own helper in handlbars if you really want to. Something like `ternary(a==true, "a", "b")`. For more information on that see the [documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html). The idea from m90 is not the idea behind handlebars. The idea is to not have explicit code in your templates, only calls to helpers and objects.

Answer (score 22):

The `if` helper can be used as a ternary operator by passing three arguments to it.

In the following example, a button has a default value of `"Save Changes"`, but when `model.isSaving` is true, then the value temporarily changes to `Saving...`.

```
<button>{{if model.isSaving "Saving..." "Save Changes"}}</button>
```

...alternatively, used within another helper:

```
{{input type="submit" value=(if model.isSaving "Saving..." "Save Changes")}}
```

Comment: @majman I've added a code sample to demonstrate what I believe to be the best answer.

Comment: Does not work for me. Had to resort to `{{#if model.isSaving}}"Saving..."{{else}}"Save Changes"{{/if}}`

Answer (score 5):

this works for me

```
{{#if final}} "Final" {{^}} "Interim" {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a helper for this (pay attention that other helpers can also be used inside)
https://gist.github.com/terion-name/d87ed8907f1bb2e25f32

```
// app/helpers/iftrue.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export function iftrue(params) {
  if (params[0]) {
    return params.length === 2 ? params[0] : params[1];
  }
  if (params.length === 2) {
    return params[1];
  } else if (params.length === 3) {
    return params[2];
  }
  return null;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(iftrue);
```

With two parameters: if first parameter evaluates to true it will be printed, otherwise second

```
{{iftrue project.price 'N/A'}} // $9.99
{{iftrue project.priceNotAvailable 'N/A'}} // N/A
```

With three parameters: if first parameter evaluates to true second will be printed, otherwise third

```
// If deadline is set formatted date will be printed, otherwise 'N/A'
{{iftrue project.deadline (moment-format project.deadline 'DD.MM.YYYY') 'N/A'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This below code can be used for ternary or any kind of expression eval.

> Warning: please use this code in scenario where eval can be used safely.

```
{{#if (myfunc "(a[0] + 1) % 2 === 0" arg1)}}

{{/if}}

{{#if (myfunc "(a[0] + a[1]) % 2 === 0" arg1 arg2)}}

{{/if}}
```

handlebar helper function

```
myfunc: (exp, ...a) => {
    return eval(exp);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the built-in `if` helper used to support use as a ternary operator but no longer does so. I overrode it as follows so it can be used either as a block-helper or ternary operator.

```
if(...args: any[]) {
    const options = args.pop();
    const {fn} = options;
    if(args.length < (fn ? 1 : 2)) {
        throw new Handlebars.Exception(
            fn ?
                '#if requires exactly one argument' : 
                'if requires two or three arguments'
        );
    }
    let conditional = args.shift();
    if(typeof conditional === 'function')
        conditional = conditional.call(this);
    // Default behavior is to render the positive path if the value is truthy and not empty.
    // The `includeZero` option may be set to treat the condtional as purely not empty based on the
    // behavior of isEmpty. Effectively this determines if 0 is handled by the positive path or negative.
    if ((!options.hash.includeZero && !conditional) || Utils.isEmpty(conditional)) {
        if(fn)
            return options.inverse(this);
        let [, b] = args;
        return typeof b === 'function' ? b.call(this) : b;
    }
    if(fn) return fn(this);
    const [a] = args;
    return typeof a === 'function' ? a.call(this) : a;
}
```