# How to use Handlebars ternary helper?

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11916194/770127), I wrote a helper like

```
module.exports.register = function (Handlebars) {
    Handlebars.registerHelper('ternary', function(test, yes, no) {
        return test ? yes : no;
    });
};
```

I'm certain that the helper is loaded and being defined but can't figure out the syntax to use it. I tried using it like

```
<div>{{ternary(true, 'yes', 'no')}}</div>
```

but that gives an [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble/) build error

```
Warning: Parse error on line 10:
...<div>{{ternary(true, 'yes',
----------^
Expecting 'ID', 'DATA', got 'INVALID' Use --force to continue.
```

What is the proper syntax to use a helper like that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Handlebars helpers: http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers don't follow the JavaScript syntax in the templates. You can use them like this:

```
<div>{{ternary true "yes" "no"}}</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Update 7/14/2017

Since both string are considered as truthy value in JavaScript, I have changed my code to the following:

```
{{input value=email placeholder="Enter Email" class="form-control"
    disabled=(if isResetting 1 0)
}}
```

============================

Original Answer

How about trying to use inline if `{{if}}`?

```
{{if user.isAdmin "True" "False" }}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, based on the documentation:
https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#if

```
{{#each langs }}
    <a 
        class="navbar-item {{#if active}}is-active{{else}}{{/if}}" 
        href="#{{code}}"
    >
        {{label}}
    </a>
{{/each}}
```