# How to pass conditional string to ember component attribute using concat?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

What is the correct way to pass the conditional string when assigning the component's attribute using ember [`concat()`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.6/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/concat?anchor=concat) method?

Consider the following

```
{{#my-compontent class=(concat (dasherize model.name)"-row")}}
  {{model.name}}
{{/my-component}}
```

What I want to do is adding the `--disabled` postfix conditionally, based on `model.disabled` property.

What I have tried:

```
{{#my-compontent class=(concat (dasherize model.name)"-row{{if model.disabled '--disabled'}}")}}
  {{model.name}}
{{/my-component}}
```

Resulting in:

```
<div class="component-name-row{{if model.disabled '--disabled}}">
  Component name
</div>
```

The other thing I tried was using `ternary` helper, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29459774/6439240):

```
{{#my-compontent class=(concat (dasherize model.name)"-row"(ternary model.disabled '--disabled' ''))}}
  {{model.name}}
{{/my-component}}
```

but it crashed:

> Assertion Failed: A helper named "ternary" could not be found

Is there any way to do that? If not, how would I achieve the same effect using a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, 5 minutes after asking I found out the answer myself:

```
{{#my-compontent class=(concat (dasherize model.name)"-row(if model.disabled '--disabled')")}}
  {{model.name}}
{{/my-component}}
```

The clue is to use `(if condition 'string')` over `{{if condition 'string'}}`.

Comment: You can do `(concat (dasherize appName) "-row" (if true '--disabled'))`, if you find it more readable.

Comment: You might also find this proposal interesting: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/issues/623